# How to find complement of an RDD in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I have an RDD in which there exist only 3 different keys, however the values can be different and the combination of (key,value) is unique. I sample from this RDD using `sampleByKey` without replacement. Now I'd like to find those elements which are not chosen in the sampling. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 1)])
rdd_in = rdd.sampleByKey(False, {'a': 0.5, 'b': 0.5, 'c': 0.5}, seed=3)
print rdd_in.collect()
# [('a', 2), ('b', 2), ('c', 1)]
print rdd.subtract(rdd_in).collect() 
# [('a', 1), ('b', 1)]
```